# Get the adjecent div id using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple java script powered picture puzzle. so far what I've done is create a div which sort of work as the parent, and inside that div, I've created 9 div elements to represent each part of the picture ( it's a 3x3 puzzle ). This is the CSS styling I've used for the picture element divs.

```
.part{
background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
background-position: top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
}

 #part{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
border: 1px dotted #fff;
}
```

what my concept is, if the user clicks on a div element, the script should check for adjacent div elements. if the element has no background image assigned, it should get the values of the clicked element.

My question is, How to get the element id of the adjacent div from the div the user clicked!

Comment: What if you give ids containing the position in the grid, that way knowing the current coordinates allows you to easily find adjacent divs, example using ids like `tile_X_Y` ...

Comment: In a 3x3 puzzle you need 9 divs right?

Comment: I actually used 8 divs and figured that using 9 divs is easy! :)

Comment: According to your css I assume that you are assigning the id `part` to all of the 9 divs? Do not do that. Use classes instead!

Comment: I used classes to assign the part of the picture.. what I did now is gave each div a different id and used inline css to style each div. will that be a matter.

Comment: Please check the jsFiddle in my edited post

Answer (score 1):

You can access adjacent div by using [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling) property of dom object

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Ankur´s answer, but I have to advise you that you have to be very careful with nextSibling. Have a look at following mark up:

```
<div id="Div1">Text1</div>
<div id="Div2">Text2</div>
```

In chrome `document.getElementById("Div1").nextSibling` will return the div with the id `Div2`. In IE however the same line returns a #Text node refering to the whitespace between both `div` tags.

To make sure that you will get the next `div` try the following.

```
var div = document.getElementById("Div1");
do {
    div = div.nextSibling;
} while (div !== null && div.tagName !== "DIV");
```

EDIT: I set up a jsFiddle that demonstrates what I might think you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/9q6vz/

Comment: so, let's say this. What I have is a map of div elements. I'm trying to get the next element id using the element that I click.. how can I figure out the top, left, bottom & right elements.! I'm confused at the moment! :(

Comment: So you actually want to get up to 4 different divs by clicking on a div (assuming you are clicking on the div in the middle)?

Comment: I used the nextSibling to get the id of the next div on a corner div. but google chrome reported that it's undefined..

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri This code is buggy. In while loop, he should check if div is null.